# MudBlazor - Unexpected results when using MudAutocomplete

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I am using MudAutocomplete to provide to the user some input suggestions in search box.
I also use MudCard to display the results of filtered items based on the user selected value the list suggestions or search box. The markup is below:

```
<MudAutocomplete T="string" Placeholder="Search.." @bind-Value="SearchText" 
    SearchFunc="@GetSearchSugestions"
    ResetValueOnEmptyText="true"
    CoerceText="true" CoerceValue="true"
    AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" AdornmentColor="Color.Primary" />

@foreach(var item in FilteredItems)
{  
   <MudCard>
     <MudCardContent>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">@item.GroupName</MudText>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.subtitle2">@item.Question</MudText>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body1">@item.Answer</MudText>
     </MudCardContent>
   </MudCard>
   <MudDivider />
}
```

The code behind is

`@code
{

```
 public string SearchText { get; set; } = string.Empty;
 public List<string> Suggestions { get; set; } = new List<string>();
 public List<Faq> Items {get; set;} = default!;

 public List<Faq> FilteredItems {get; set;} = default!;

 protected override void OnInitialized()
 {
    Items = new List<Faq>()
    {
        new Faq()
        {
            GroupName = "AI",
            Question = "How soon AI will change human labour?",
            Answer = "Very soon"
        },
        new Faq()
        {
            GroupName = "AI",
            Question = "is ChatGP a threat to humanity?",
            Answer = "No, ChatGPT is there to help humanity"
        },
        new Faq()
        {
            GroupName = "War",
            Question = "Is world war 3 inevitable?",
            Answer = "Yes"
        },
        new Faq()
        {
            GroupName = "War",
            Question = "how did world war 2 started?",
            Answer = "Escalation in Europe"
        }
    };
   
    FilteredItems = Items;
 }

 private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetSearchSugestions(string text)
 {
    //..Simulating API call
    await Task.Delay(2);

    var suggestions = new List<string>();

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        //..Logic for filtering and making suggestions
        var filteredItems = FindFaqsBySearchText(text);
        foreach (var faq in filteredItems)
        {
            if (faq.Question.Contains(text.ToLower()))
            {
                suggestions.Add(faq.Question);
            }

        
            var words = faq.Answer.Split().Select(a => a.Trim());
            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                if (word.Contains(text.ToLower()) && !suggestions.Contains(text))
                {
                    suggestions.Add(word);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return (IEnumerable<string>) suggestions;

    
 }

 private List<Faq> FindFaqsBySearchText(string text)
 {
    FilteredItems = Items.Where(f => f.Question.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower())
                                    || f.Answer.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower())
                                    || f.GroupName.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower()))
                             .ToList();

    return FilteredItems;
 }
```

}`
There are two unexpected results :

1. If i clear the search box after typing , the area of of the mudcard should display the initial list of content.

2.If i select the suggetion in the search box, i should be provided corresponding exact content not a list of content .
You have to play with my demo in order to see this kind of behaviour.
Thank you for the feedback, i appreciate.
The working demo is https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wacdYFuqTPFFlJpF

Comment: Which results are unexpected and how would you expect them to work?

Comment: There are two unexpected results : 
1--If i clear the search box , the area of of the mudcard should display the initial list of content.
2--If i select the suggetion in the search box, i should be provided corresponding exact content not a list of content .
You have to play with my demo in order to see the behaviour.
Thank you for your feedback mate, appreciate

Comment: Edited your demo and tried to fix your problem: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wEQHEFagAqxrRDIQ. Basically I changed the `FilteredItems` to a calculated property that returns either the filtered list or all items based on if the `SearchText` property is null or empty.